# Faster way to pass a integer-literal?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if this code can be condensed, seeing as I don't need the UINT for anything other than the one line.

```
UINT vps = 1;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
md3dImmediateContext->RSGetViewports(&vps, &viewport);
```

Do I have to declare a new variable just to pass in the first parameter?

Comment: Pretty much.  Why does this function take arguments by pointer?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth [Apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff476477(v=vs.85).aspx) it is also used for output. MHA just doesn't care about the output, I guess.

Comment: That is correct, I won't use the output for now.

Answer (score 3):

The function `RSGetViewports` uses the pointer to modify the value of the `int` so that is visible outside the function. In this way, you can think of that argument as being both an input and output argument. Of course, there must be an object available for it to modify. If you were to pass an integer literal, there would be no such object.

Comment: won't the temporary object be destroy before the call to `RSGetViewports`?

Comment: @tiridactil Oh damn, you're absolutely right. The binding to the return value won't extend its lifetime. I guess I'll scrap that. I can't think of another way to make a temporary object that lasts for the entire full-expression.

Comment: I appreciate your try though.